# How to sort Map array of arrays based on values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, reduce

I have information coming in as a Map in Javascript.

I want to sort it based on types I have set as an enum.

The data looks like this:

Map(5)

```
{"Adopted" => 105, "Pending" => 176, "Missing" => 3, "InterestedParties" => 45, "WaitingForPickup" => 15}
```

Though it may make more sense when seen this way:

```
new Map<string, number>([
  ['Adopted', 105],
  ['Pending', 176],
  ['Missing', 3],
  ['InterestedParties', 45],
  ['WaitingForPickup', 15],
]);
```

I want to sort this data into categories like "unadopted animals", "homed animals", "Unknown status", so I made a group of data that map to enum types (so `AnimalStatusType.Pending` is "Pending")

```
  const metricGroups = {
    unAdopted: [
      AnimalStatusType.Pending,
      AnimalStatusType.InterestedParties,
    ],
    adopted: [
      AnimalStatusType.Adopted,
    ],
    unknown: [
      AnimalStatusType.Missing,
      AnimalStatusType.WaitingForPickup
    ],
  }
```

I want to end up with my Map sorted by the three different categories adopted, unadopted, and unknown to look something like this:

```
{
  adopted: [['adopted', 105]],
  unadopted: [['pending', 176],['interestedParties', 45]],
  unknown: [ ['missing', 3],['waitingForPickup', 15]],
}
```

but I'm having a bit of difficulty finding anything that does the mapping properly. I think maybe combining `Array.from` or a reduce functionality can work, but searching mostly pulls up Javascript's .map functionality which is not helping.

```
 const GroupedData =  Array.from(animalData).reduce((acc, metric) => {
        acc[metricGroups[metric]].push(metric)
      })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `map` and `Object.entries`/`Object.fromEntries`

```js
const input = new Map([
  ['Adopted', 105],
  ['Pending', 176],
  ['Missing', 3],
  ['InterestedParties', 45],
  ['WaitingForPickup', 15],
]);

const metricGroups = {
  unAdopted: [
    "Pending",
    "InterestedParties",
  ],
  adopted: [
    "Adopted",
  ],
  unknown: [
    "Missing",
    "WaitingForPickup"
  ],
}

const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(metricGroups).map(([key, values]) => {
  return [
    key,
    values.map(value => ([value, input.get(value)]))
  ]
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just simply reduce your `metricGroups` object and map the enum values to the appropriate key-value pair in the `input`.

Note that you cannot sort an object's keys.

```js
const AnimalStatusType = {
  Adopted: 'adopted',
  InterestedParties: 'interestedParties',
  Missing: 'missing',
  Pending: 'pending',
  WaitingForPickup: 'waitingForPickup'
};

const metricGroups = {
  unAdopted: [
    AnimalStatusType.Pending,
    AnimalStatusType.InterestedParties,
  ],
  adopted: [
    AnimalStatusType.Adopted,
  ],
  unknown: [
    AnimalStatusType.Missing,
    AnimalStatusType.WaitingForPickup
  ],
};

const input = { 'Adopted': 105, 'Pending': 176, 'Missing': 3, 'InterestedParties': 45, 'WaitingForPickup': 15 };

const capitalize = (str) => str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);

const result = Object.entries(metricGroups)
  .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => ({
    ...acc,
    [key]: value.map(v => [v, input[capitalize(v)]])
  }), {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//the sortMe function sorts the list of maps by fieldName in acs/desc order 

function getASCOrder(){ // <-- create sample list map to be sorted
    var retval = new java.util.ArrayList();
    for (var i = 0; i<5 ; i++){
        var map = new java.util.HashMap();
        map.put("channelId", "3"+ i);
        map.put("some_data", "data"+ i);
        retval.add(map);
    }
    return retval;
}
 
var data = this.getASCOrder(); //<-- get sample data
data = [{channelId=30, some_data=data0}, {channelId=31, some_data=data1}, {channelId=32, some_data=data2}, {channelId=33, some_data=data3}, {channelId=34, some_data=data4}]

var sorted_array  = sortMe(data, "channelId", false); // <-- sort data in reverse order

sorted_array = [{channelId=34, some_data=data4},{channelId=33, some_data=data3},{channelId=32, some_data=data2},{channelId=31, some_data=data1}, {channelId=30, some_data=data0}]

function sortMe(arrayList, sortFieldName, asc) {

   var icount = arrayList.size();
   var temp = null;
   for (var i = 0; i < icount; i++) {
      var n = i + 1;
      if (n < icount) {
         var curMap = arrayList.get(i);
         var nextMap = arrayList.get(n);
        if(asc){ 
             if(curMap.get(sortFieldName) > nextMap.get(sortFieldName)) {
                arrayList.remove(n);
                arrayList.add(i, nextMap);
                sortMe(arrayList, sortFieldName, asc); // <-- recursive call here
             }
         } else { 
             if (curMap.get(sortFieldName) < nextMap.get(sortFieldName)) {
                arrayList.remove(n);
                arrayList.add(i, nextMap);
                sortMe(arrayList, sortFieldName, asc);
             }        
         } 
      }
   }
   return arrayList;
}
```

Comment: `new java.util.ArrayList` and `new java.util.HashMap`? Are you sure you wanted to answer this question?